# Vue.js router error: devtools-api appropriate loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I'm new to vue and those types of webservers, so please forgive me. Before I install vue-router my project is fine, but after I install it, I've got this really strange error  in any new vue project (created using the vue cli):

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                           4:52:15 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/@vue/devtools-api/lib/esm/proxy.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { HOOK_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_SET } from './const';
| export class ApiProxy {
>     target;
|     targetQueue;
|     proxiedTarget;

 @ ./node_modules/@vue/devtools-api/lib/esm/index.js 3:0-35 14:40-48
 @ ./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.8.0.1:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I do not exactly know what this even means, or how I could start fixing it.
Since it happens in any new vue project, my working hypothesis is, that I have somehow messed something up with my global npm packages (or npm itself).
For context I am on an Ubuntu Server (20.04), and once upgraded npm itself from 6.14.x to 8.x.x after I was prompted very largely with the possibility and thought that was a good idea. Then suddenly I got a bunch of vulnerabilities and now have downgraded to 6.14.15. Possibly that might have something to do with it (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Met the same problem. Changed Node version to 14.18.1 instead of 17.3.0 (nvm use 14.18.1).

Comment: Thanks! That solved it