# Vue JS 3 Application to run in older Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, firefox, babeljs

I'm developing an app in VueJS 3 and it seems that's working on my local computer.
But I have to make it runs also on older browsers like Firefox 38 Chrome 49.

My app uses some "fetch" functions to load content from api, to authenticate, to send commands, etc. After reading the following 2 links I believe I have some issues with it (despite it should works on CH 42). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API and [Babel not Polyfilling Fetch when using babel-preset-env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908044/babel-not-polyfilling-fetch-when-using-babel-preset-env)
. What it is your opinion?

I have babel and in package.json the following settings:

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "Chrome > 48",
 ]
```

**But the errors received in Firefox and Chrome are very cryptic and I don't know what how should I transpile that function. I would focus on Chrome 49 and I'll add some context**

*Indeed the async function is available after Chrome 55. But I don't know how to convert it*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

For example in Chrome 49 I have the following console error on the following page: **webpack:///./node_modules/@vue/devtools-api/esm/proxy.js**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   proxy.js:94

The content of that file is:

```
import { HOOK_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_SET } from './const';
export class ApiProxy {
constructor(plugin, hook) {
    this.target = null;
    this.targetQueue = [];
    this.onQueue = [];
    this.plugin = plugin;
    this.hook = hook;
    const defaultSettings = {};
    if (plugin.settings) {
        for (const id in plugin.settings) {
            const item = plugin.settings[id];
            defaultSettings[id] = item.defaultValue;
        }
    }
    const localSettingsSaveId = `__vue-devtools-plugin-settings__${plugin.id}`;
    let currentSettings = Object.assign({}, defaultSettings);
    try {
        const raw = localStorage.getItem(localSettingsSaveId);
        const data = JSON.parse(raw);
        Object.assign(currentSettings, data);
    }
    catch (e) {
        // noop
    }
    this.fallbacks = {
        getSettings() {
            return currentSettings;
        },
        setSettings(value) {
            try {
                localStorage.setItem(localSettingsSaveId, JSON.stringify(value));
            }
            catch (e) {
                // noop
            }
            currentSettings = value;
        },
    };
    if (hook) {
        hook.on(HOOK_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_SET, (pluginId, value) => {
            if (pluginId === this.plugin.id) {
                this.fallbacks.setSettings(value);
            }
        });
    }
    this.proxiedOn = new Proxy({}, {
        get: (_target, prop) => {
            if (this.target) {
                return this.target.on[prop];
            }
            else {
                return (...args) => {
                    this.onQueue.push({
                        method: prop,
                        args,
                    });
                };
            }
        },
    });
    this.proxiedTarget = new Proxy({}, {
        get: (_target, prop) => {
            if (this.target) {
                return this.target[prop];
            }
            else if (prop === 'on') {
                return this.proxiedOn;
            }
            else if (Object.keys(this.fallbacks).includes(prop)) {
                return (...args) => {
                    this.targetQueue.push({
                        method: prop,
                        args,
                        resolve: () => { },
                    });
                    return this.fallbacks[prop](...args);
                };
            }
            else {
                return (...args) => {
                    return new Promise(resolve => {
                        this.targetQueue.push({
                            method: prop,
                            args,
                            resolve,
                        });
                    });
                };
            }
        },
    });
}
async setRealTarget(target) {
    this.target = target;
    for (const item of this.onQueue) {
        this.target.on[item.method](...item.args);
    }
    for (const item of this.targetQueue) {
        item.resolve(await this.target[item.method](...item.args));
    }
}
}
```

I tried to change anything I found:

> vue.config.js

```
    transpileDependencies: [
    "config",
    "vue",
    "vue-router",
    "vuex",
    "xml2js"
],
```

> package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"config": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
"vue": "^3.2.26",
"vue-router": "^4.0.12",
"vuex": "^4.0.2",
"xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"@babel/cli": "^7.16.8",
"@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
"@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"eslint": "^6.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
"defaults",
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"not dead",
"Chrome > 48"
  ]
```

> babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
  [
      '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
      {
          useBuiltIns: "usage",
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          targets: {
              "chrome": "49"
          },
          }
  ]
  ]
};
```

> main.js

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './_store'
createApp(App).use(router).use(store).mount('#app');
```

Comment: The first thing you need to check is what versions correspond to common modern features of JS that are expected to be used - classes, proxy, `async`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#browser_compatibility . You may notice that they aren't available in C48. browserslist affects your own code, not node_modules. You need to force this per library with `transpileDependencies`. And the problem is that you'll likely fail to do this because Vue 3 doesn't support old browsers at all. It's not workable in IE11. This could be better for Chrome but I wouldn't hope

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, I didn't know about transpile :(, anyway I only need one, Firefox OR Chrome. At the 1st stages I tested on mdn and believed is ok. Thanks for help. I'll study it.

Comment: You'll have much better chances at making GC49 work because it's newer and supports ES2015 (classes and proxy), you'll only need to cover ES2017+ (async) transpilation and make sure that ES2016+ polyfills are applied (I believe that babel is supposed to do that automatically)

Comment: I've tried anything a could find online. Somethings I believe are really useless but 1st make it works than I'll polish it. I'll add in comment.

Comment: Did you try to add `@vue/devtools-api` into `transpileDependencies` ?

Answer (score 0):

i setup a new vue 3 project and added async/await and fetch and did a build and it workes in chrome 48

I modified hello world component to

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {msg : ""}
  },
  mounted() {

    async function fetchMoviesJSON() {
      const response = await fetch('https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json');
      const movies = await response.json();
      return movies;
    }

    fetchMoviesJSON().then(data => {
      this.msg = data; // fetched movies
    });


  }
}
</script>
```

added `"Chrome > 47"` to `browserslist`

also i installed `browserslist`

1. can you run after installing browserslist `npx browserslist` and check if you see chrome 47 there?
2. I saw in your error `dev-tools` i think it might be just the Vue dev tools

**Update:**
added vue router and installed the vue dev tools and when i run with `serve` i can see that the proxy file was compiled there and no errors.

are you building it in dev mode?

I would recommend you to clean up your babel plugins and try with the simple way.
also please let know the node/nom version. i read it might be the problem, and you should try to update node see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70426167/12239849)